# C# SendKeyPress does not always bring window to front

Tags: c#, winapi

On my CNC machine, running Win 10 Pro, I have a C# console application that monitors for a physical button press on the machines control panel.  When a button is pressed, I forward it on with SendKeyPress to the CNC control software.

Most of the time this brings the CNC software to the front, which is what I want.  Sometimes it just flashes the icon on the task bar.

Is there a way I can ensure that the CNC software is always brought to the front?  It is a dedicated CNC PC, so this is a desired behavior.

The relevant part of the code I use is:

```
        if (mKeys == null)
        {
            // TODO:  Populate these from a config file
            mKeys = new BitToKey[] {
                new BitToKey(450, "{F8}"),
                new BitToKey(451, "%d"),         // % = ALT, + = SHIFT, ^ = CTRL
                new BitToKey(452, "")
            };
        }
        var processName = "cncm";

        for (var i = 0; i < mKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            Skinning.Plc.IOState ioSt;
            var ret = m_skin.plc.GetMemoryState(mKeys[i].Bit, out ioSt);
            if (ret == Skinning.ReturnCode.SUCCESS)
            {
                var state = ioSt == Skinning.Plc.IOState.IO_LOGICAL_1;
                if (state == true && mKeys[i].LastState == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("PLC memory bit " + mKeys[i].Bit.ToString() + " set");
                    SendKeyPress(mKeys[i].Key, processName);
                }
                mKeys[i].LastState = state;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PLC memory bit read failed");
                // Assume this fail was caused by skinnings failure to reach CNC12 (probably CNC12 was closed)
                m_skin = null;
                mKeys = null; // Resets previous key states
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since your program received user input, why don't you simply call [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow)? Clearly, if you received user input, your program is the foreground process, so it is eligible to pass foreground activation along.

Comment: My program makes a DLL call to another part of the CNC software that fetches some values that indicate if a physical button is pressed.  The buttons are on a control panel read by the CNC hardware and passed to the CNC control program running on the PC.  There is no Windows user input as such when the button is pressed.  My console program does not come to the foreground when a button is pressed.  Does SetForegroundWindow work when your window is not the foreground one?

Comment: This sounds like you are in full control over the system you are running on, so you can probably arrange for having [foreground activation permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow). Alternatively, have the CNC application [locked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-locksetforegroundwindow) as the foreground process. Though you probably want to be using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) instead of `SendKeyPress`.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think my console application meets the requirements for activating the foreground window based in the Remarks section of AllowSetForegroundWindow documentation.  I will look into UI automation though as have never heard of that before.